# Segmentation fault with VLC 2.2.1 on Debian

Tags: debian, vlc, segmentation-fault

I know there are plenty of questions like this across the Internet but no fix for this seems to work for me.

I'm having an issue where VLC segfaults on startup (NOT when opening a file). No other console output is available.

I've tried:

- updating `microcode` with `sudo apt-get install intel-microcode`.
- installing `libgme` `sudo apt-get install libgme-dev`,
- Installing `libqt5x11extras5`.
- Upgrading all packages.
- Reinstalling VLC.

...and a variety of other commands, such as

- `vlc -I skins`
- `/usr/lib/vlc/vlc-cache-gen -f usr/lib/vlc/plugins`
- `vlc -I qt4 --reset-config --reset-plugins-cache`

Of course, I tried restarting the computer after all of this. Nothing solved the segfault or even gave a hint of progress.

**System Info**

- Debian Jessie 64 bit
- Intel Core i5-6600
- GeForce GTX 960
- VLC version 2.2.1

The stack trace can be found [here](http://hastebin.com/raw/pibafayebe).

I found some articles/forums referring to the use of `gdb` to get a backtrace or some more information, but it just gives me `no debugging symbols found`.

Comment: I have the same problem and I suspect a shared library problem.

Comment: I too have the same problem for ubuntu 16.04 on acer laptop with amd A8 processor.Any help can be appreciated.Thank you.